# Javascript weird behaviour when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement this [html5up template](https://html5up.net/ethereal). I'm facing a weird problem, when I click the gallery pictures, the horizontal scroll goes to the beginning and then it's broken. It also happens when you right click the wrapper.

I added this while trying to debug

```
$wrapper.mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
        alert('Rigth click');
        break;
    }
});
```

Now, when I right click, I get an alert, but after that, the bug is gone, and I can click the gallery images.

Comment: Put the full code and markup of a failing example in your question.

Comment: Remind me NOT to go to your new site, that horizontal scroll is IMHO horrid from a UI expectation perspective i.e. mouse wheel.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss agree, but is a just a "Save the date" single page thing. ;)

Comment: By your description it almost sounds like it is doing a page refresh or some similar effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that the `$wrapper.mousedown` is already in use, but apparently got some errors/issues (maybe it is trying to use a method of a missing library). During your debug session you have removed the bad code by overriding this function. That is why is works now.

Please add some more code, so we can help you with your problem.

Comment: I tried to pasted it in jsfiddle but it is too big, I think. Here is only the JS https://pastebin.com/uUCb4XyA, in the original website you can download the code, if you'd like https://html5up.net/ethereal

Comment: I've downloaded the template, but everything seems fine. The Pastebin code shows that the images needs to be surrounded by `<a></a>` tags with the `href` attribute linked to the image (see Pastebin line: 655).

Comment: In the index.html of the downloaded code, tried to right click inside the main strip. Another test is to reload and click a gallery image. It also happens on the live website.

Comment: I find that the Edge browser have some difficulty with dragging the content with the right-mouse button. This problem however lies in the Edge browser itself. Other browsers like Chrome and Firefox works just fine. Other than that, I can't find your problem; sorry.

Comment: You were right. I commented out (for now), all the usage of "mousedown" and the bug is gone! Thanks!